# Navigate to nested navigator in other stack without delay or animation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v6

How can you navigate to a different stack's child navigator without animation or delay using react-navigation/native@^6.0.13?

[image]

I'm able to navigate from **CreateOrderScreen** to **OrderScreen** but because the **OrderNavigator** is a child of **HomeNavigator** there's a delay in the navigation.
Currently when you navigate, you first land on the **HomeScreen** and after that you are navigated, (with animation), to the **OrderScreen**. I do not wish to see **HomeScreen** at all, I want to go straight to **OrderScreen**.

```
navigation.navigate('Root', {
  screen: 'Home',
  params: {
    screen: 'Order',
    params: {
      screen: 'OrderScreen',
      params: {
        id: 213090,
        title: `test`,
        state: OrderState.Confirmed,
      },
    },
  },
})
```

What I've tried:

- Removing animation on the StackNavigators, (did not help, animation was skipped but still delay, you still see HomeScreen)
- Replace/push without success

One interesting sidenote is that if **OrderScreen** is already mounted when navigating, (while **CreateOrderScreen** is active), no delay or animation is shown and everything works as intended.